# Evaluation of $I_{a,b} = \int_{1}^{+\infty} \frac{\ \exp{(-at)}}{ 1-bt} \ \mathrm{d}t $

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

How to evaluate this integral:

> $$I_{a,b} = \int_{1}^{\infty} \frac{\  \exp\left(-a t\right)}{ 1-b t} \mathrm{d}t $$
>   where $a, b  \in  R^*_+$ ?

Comment: In terms of the "exponential integral" function, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral

Comment: Consider the substitution $u=1-bt$ first and $v=au/b$ second; compare with [$\mathrm{Ei}(\cdot)$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).

Comment: Thanks GEdgar, anon this was very helpful.

Comment: @jack Could you write your own answer and accept it so that this question gets answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $b<1$ so that $1-bt >0 $.

Thanks to @anon this can be done by making the substitution :
1). $u=1-bt$,  with $\mathrm{d}t = (-1/b) \mathrm{d}u$, so :
$$I_{a,b} =\frac{\exp(-\frac{a}{b})}{b} \   \int\limits_{-\infty}^{1-b} \frac{\  \exp\left(\frac{a}{b} u\right)}{u} \mathrm{d}u$$

2.)  $v=\frac{a}{b}u$ with $\frac{\mathrm{d}v}{v}=\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u}$ , then:
$$I_{a,b} =\frac{\exp(-\frac{a}{b})}{b} \   \int\limits_{-\infty}^{(1-b)\frac{a}{b}} \frac{\  \exp(v)}{v} \mathrm{d}v$$

Hence.
$$I_{a,b} =\frac{\exp(-\frac{a}{b})}{b} \   Ei({(1-b)\frac{a}{b}})$$  where 
$Ei(x) =\int\limits_{-\infty}^{x} \frac{\  \exp(t)}{t} \mathrm{d}t $ : The *Exponential Integral Function*